# Unexpected output in C - printf

Tags: c, printf

I am using Dev C++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32 Bit compiler.
I was trying to find the order of evaluation of expressions in printf function for which i made the program:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int x=0;
        printf("%d %d",x++,++x);
        return 0;
    }
```

If the order of evaluation turns out to be left to right, then the output will be 0 2 and for right to left the output will be 1 1. But the output comes out to be 1 2. How is this possible?
If I write:

```
    printf("%d %d",x++,x);
```

then the output is 0 1 which indicates that order of evaluation is right to left and instead if i write:

```
    printf("%d %d",x,x++);
```

then the output is 1 0 which indicates that order of evaluation is left to right. Please explain me why I am getting contradictory outputs.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* - The order of evaluation is not defined (see the reference page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)

Comment: What this actually is is a load of *undefined behaviour*. But plus one for this particular variant of the common question - you've spent a lot of time building the case, even if the answer is obvious once you know it.

Comment: You might find this video useful: https://vimeo.com/68390478 - especially about 7m55s into the video :)